# MongoDB documents write conflicts in multi-threaded application

Tags: java, mongodb, multithreading

I'm running a Java application that spawns multiple threads taking care of writing objects to a mongoDB collection. The input is a huge list of objects, and each thread is taking care of a portion of this list.

I run the code with relatively small loads around 20K documents and it works Perfect. But when the list size exceeds a certain threshold. I start getting `WriteConflict` exception from MongoDB, even though I verified that each thread is operating on a separate portion of the list and they're not overlapping nor trying to persist same documents twice.

What can be the cause for such Exception? The exception message is not quite helpful.